# Using jQuery Bootgrid Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-bootgrid

How exactly are you meant to use the methods for jQuery BootGrid?

I've tried:

```
$("#presentation-listing-api").bootgrid('remove', [uid]);
```

Doesn't seem to be working?

It's not helpful that the documentation isn't quite finished yet.

Comment: Show us your full code and html.

Comment: Well their [online demos](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#1) seem to work. You could copy one of them as a starting point?#

Comment: The online examples they have don't actually show the use of methods like 'remove' etc. I guess this is really a question for the author. There's not much code to share other than the fact that #presentation-listing-api is an HTML table.

Answer (score 10):

It should be noted, as of version [**1.3.1**], the "**remove**" feature is not supported when using the **ajax** option. There is a note in the source that reads

> [ todo: implement ajax DELETE]

An alternative could be something like this:

```
$('[data-row-id="'+uid+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: Note that this removes the representation of the row, but if you change page (from the pagination buttons) and come back, the row reappears

Comment: @Rombus If not using the **ajax** option, that is correct. However, I assumed anyone using the ajax method (and associated JSON objects) would _also_ be handling removal of the row from the results. All of this is probably meaningless, since I doubt the original question was related to server-side / **ajax** data anyway. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 5):

The way to do it was kind of convoluted but I figured it out...

**You have to mark your id column as an identifier and the type to numeric** like this:

```
<th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
```

Then, MAKE SURE the values in that column are unique!!!

Then call the remove like this:

```
rows[0] = uid;
$("#presentation-listing-api").bootgrid('remove', rows);
```

What I did was took the Commands demo and modified it to load just some data then worked on getting the remove to work.

Here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/zszc8zL6/

Comment: Also very important to note that data-type="numeric" is necessary or else it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the "id" variable as an **integer** in the associated object you are using to fill the table. With *parseInt()* worked even with *ajax: false*.